# Error in window.default(): 'start' cannot be after 'end' in R time series analysis

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to fit a one-step ahead time series model, so I need to extend my train set at each iteration as follows:

```
library(forecast)
(AirPassengers)
in.sample  <- window(AirPassengers, c(1949,1), c(1958,12))
out.sample <- window(AirPassengers, c(1959,1), c(1960,12))
# initialize
hw_forecast <- numeric(); day_fcast <- character()
class(day_fcast) <- "Date"
 
for (i in 1:length(out.sample)) {
         in.sample <- window(AirPassengers, start = c(1991, 1), 
                              end = as.Date(time(out.sample[i]))-1)
         fit= hw(train.ts, seasonal="additive")
         fore1 <- forecast(fit, h=1)
         hw_forecast[i] <- fore1$mean # fore1[[2]][[1]]
         day_fcast[i] <- as.Date(time(out.sample[i,]))
     }
```

However, this error is reported:

```
Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' cannot be after 'end'
```

I would appreciated it if you could let me know how to determine the end of window?

Comment: Is it probably because you are referring to 1991 in AirPassengers in the first line of the for loop, which does not exist?

Comment: @JamesAzam I think `as.Date(time(out.sample[i]))-1)` extracts the value of Airpassenger not the date. But I could not resolve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simpler to use the `subset()` function for this problem.

```
library(forecast)

in.sample  <- window(AirPassengers, c(1949,1), c(1958,12))
out.sample <- window(AirPassengers, c(1959,1), c(1960,12))
# initialize
hw_forecast <- out.sample*NA

for (i in seq_along(out.sample)) {
  train.ts <- subset(AirPassengers, end = length(in.sample) + i)
  fit <- hw(train.ts, seasonal="additive")
  fore1 <- forecast(fit, h=1)
  hw_forecast[i] <- fore1$mean
}
```

- `train.ts` is undefined in your code. I have assumed you mean the `ts` object created on the previous line.
- These are monthly data, so it makes no sense to use `as.Date()`. Instead, I have made `hw_forecast` a `ts` object with the correct start and frequency attributes.
- `as.Date()` can't be used to set the `frequency` of a `ts` object, as the `frequency` should be numeric.